# Printing File Contents after HTML button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to read a users local file *after* a button is pressed. Right now, the code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<label for="evidence_file">Please choose a file to upload for evidence:</label><br><input type="file" id="fileElem"><br>

<button type="button" id="Submit">Submit Evidence </button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("Submit").onclick = function () {


  file = document.getElementById("fileElem").files[0];

  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(file) {
    console.log(file);
   };

  fr.readAsTest(file);
  }
```

However, the file reader "onload" function is never running. By this, I mean that the function is never triggered (and the console never prints file). Is there a reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: You have a type: fr.readAsTe**x**t(file);

Answer (score 1):

In your code example you call `readAsTest` which is a typo for `readAsText`. If that's a copy and paste mistake and your code works, try adding an error handler to the file reader and see if it gives you something to go on.